# How to make my Debian useful - 1 CDs installed, clean Debian

Tags: linux, installation, debian, installation-package

I have problem with debian. After 1 year working on Ubuntu and problems with Ubuntu on VirtualBox I decide to moved to Debian(I know that Ubuntu is son of Debian, but Debian don't make a problem with installation). Ok, I have download first CD.. i thought that it will be enough to do something.. but I was wrong. I have connection to the internet (checked by ping some sites), but i cannot find any package, for example dkms. I would like to install some Desktop Environment( i have only command line) e.g Xfce, but still I can't find package. Is there any way to make my debian useful or I need to download more CDs and install it again? Sudo apt-get update do not work at all, it returns that everything is updated.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would help if you identify exactly what you downloaded (link, iso name).

Answer (score 0):

You can install Xfce by issuing `sudo apt-get install xfce4`.

If you have a working internet connection during installation, you do not need to download all CDs. The first one or even the netboot CD is enough. During installation you can chose to install a desktop environment (per default GNOME); or before starting the actual installation watch through the presented menus (just after booting the installer), you'll find alternate desktop environments to select from.